# Eclipse plugin: Custom icon for a Marker

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to specify a custom icon for a marker. Sadly, the icon that I chose is not displayed.

Here's the relevant parts of the plugin.xml file (the project id "x"):

```
<extension
      id="xmlProblem"
      name="XML Problem"
      point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
   <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>
   <persistent
         value="true">
   </persistent>
</extension>

<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerImageProviders">
   <imageprovider
         markertype="x.xmlProblem"
         icon="icons/marker.png"
         id="xmlProblemImageProvider">
   </imageprovider>
</extension>
```

I also tried specifying a class (implementing `IMarkerImageProvider`) instead of an icon, but that `getImagePath()` method of the class does not get called.

Any thoughts on how to make custom marker icons work?

Desperately, yours.

-Itay

**Update**

VonC's solution is pretty much correct, except that you must *not* specify `org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker` as a supertype of your marker. It worked only when I used `org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker` as the *only* supertype.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in my answer. Don't hesitate to edit that answer if it still misses an element to make it work like you did.

Comment: Awesome edit! Much clearer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [bug 260909](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260909) "markerImageProviders extension point does not work" (found after reading [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg60675.html))

> Tod Creasey 2009-01-21 07:32:38 EST
>
> We have never had the push to make this API because it has some inflexibility that made it generally not consumable - it was written early on to enable the first marker views for the 3 severities we use and as a result was not used by the markerSupport as it was not API.
>
> It is confusing that we have an internal extension point (we don't generally do
> that) but removing it would likely break someone without warning.

**[EDIT by Itay]**

Following on Vonc's pointers, I eventually managed to make this thing work.
Here are the relevant fragments from my `plugin.xml` (assuming the plugin name is `a.b.c`)

```
  <extension point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"   
        id="myMarker">
     <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>         
     <persistent value="true"/>
  </extension>

  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
     <type
        super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.warning"
        markerType="a.b.c.myMarker"
        name="a.b.c.myAnnotation"
        markerSeverity="1"/>
  </extension>

  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
     <specification
        annotationType="a.b.c.myAnnotation"
        icon="icons/marker.png"
        verticalRulerPreferenceKey="myMarkerIndicationInVerticalRuler"
        verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true"/>
  </extension>
```

**Pitfalls**

- The super type of the marker must be set to `org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker`. Any other value will prevent your custom icon from being used.
- When you create a marker in your code make sure its severity matches the severity value specified in the `markerSeverity` attribute at the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes` extension point. `1` means warning, etc.
- Make sure the icons folder is specified in your build.properties file (or the "build" tab at the plugin editor)
- The declaration above will only specify a custom icon. If you want to customize other attributes (color of indication at the overview ruler, etc.) follow the sample from [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg26505.html) on which this solution is based.

Comment: @eactor I cannot find the exact address, but a more recent thread might provide a better illustration: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=160387/, although beware of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260909

Comment: in marker type in the second extension point it shouldnt be the marker id defined in the first extension? What plugin you mean by a.b.c.MyMarker ?

Comment: @user847988 "in `marker` type in the second extension point it shouldnt be the `marker id` defined in the first extension?': quite possibly. You should comment under the OP's question, for Itay Maman to be notified.