# Markers view shows my marker with a red square insted of error/warning icon

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, marker

I created my own marker based on the ibm tutorial [Best practices for developing Eclipse plugins
Using markers, annotations, and decorators](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#resourcemarker_create).

In my plugin xml
I have something like this:

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"
      id="com.ibm.mymarkers.mymarker"
      name="My error">
      <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
      <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.marker"/>     
      <persistent value="true"/>
     </extension>
```

I tried also with different super types such as
`<super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>`
When I create the marker i set :

```
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
```

The problem is that the markers are shown in the markers view but without an icon (basically a red square) how can I define an icon for these markers...?

I tried the simple example from  [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#resourcemarker_create) but still I don't see any image the marker is created but no image.

```
      IMarker marker = res.createMarker(IMarker.TASK);
      marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "This a a task");
      marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Am I maybe missing some plugin that contains this images?

Comment: Have you tried it with *just* problemmarker as the super type?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extension of type `org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerImageProviders`

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerImageProviders">
   <imageprovider
         markertype="com.ibm.mymarkers.mymarker"
         icon="marker.png"
         id="myImageProvider">
   </imageprovider>
</extension>
```

**EDIT**

It seems the aforementioned extension point doesn't work (!).
Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888207/eclipse-plugin-custom-icon-for-a-marker).